# MongoDB go driver maintain sort order

Tags: mongodb, sorting, go

I query my records using this code:

```
cur, err := collection.Find(
    ctx,
    filter,
    options.Find().SetLimit(limit).SetSort(map[string]int{"timestamp": -1, "_id": -1}),
)
```

But I noticed through my mongodb log that the order changes sometimes... into _id: -1, timestamp: -1 which affects the query results. How do I make sure that timestamp comes first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A map does not have any ordering guarantees for its elements. Use a `bson.D` for documents where element ordering is important:

```
SetSort({{"timestamp",-1},{"_id":-1}})
```

Comment: ok this works  cur, err := collection.Find(
  ctx,
  filter,
  options.Find().SetLimit(limit).SetSort(bson.D{
   {Key: "timestamp", Value: -1},
   {Key: "_id", Value: -1},
  }),
 )